# Error al migrar base datos Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, artisan, wampserver

Tengo un proyecto nuevo en el cual realizo la definición de tablas de la base de datos,
al realizar el comando `php artisan migrate` me genera el siguiente error.

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))
```

Obtuve una forma de darle solución basado en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54037705/11846496) el problema es que trabajo en equipo en este proyecto para lo cual a los demás integrantes les funciona sin problema, por lo tanto se quiere evitar el uso de esta lineas que dan en la respuesta.

Utilizo [WampServer](https://www.wampserver.com/)

Realice pruebas con [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/es/index.html) y funciona sin problemas el comando, solo con wampserver no funciona, el problema es que **xampp** me causa un error en mi maquina que es bastante molesto, razon por la que quiero darle solución para **wampserver**

Comment: En tu pc ¿qué versión de MySQL usas?

Comment: @BetaM según wampServer 5.7.31